# Adding group members to eck entity with og

Tags: commerce, organic-groups, entities

I hope i didn't duplicate an issue i didn't see anything like this... Im trying to create an entity with eck and then make it a group. That I can do. But as og is seemingly designed to work with nodes not entities... the functionality of adding group members to an entity seems to be missing in entity i made..

i cant figure out how to add a member to a group from the ui with an eck entity as a group